# Parameter for XPath method in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, xpath, parameters

Excel does not accept `?` as a parameter within a query but I want `CIID` to be changed dynamically from a value in a cell.

```
select Malzeme_Kodu, MalzemeAdi as [Malzeme Adi],Miktar,Birim,BirimKodu,onhand as [Mevcut Miktar],minFiyat as [En Dusuk Fiyat], ensonalfiyati as [En Son Alis Fiyati], fiyat as [Alis Fiyati], Toplam,ted as [Tedarikci]   from (
SELECT 
N.C.value('(ColumnData)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as Malzeme_Kodu,
N.C.value('(ColumnData)[1]/@datatext','nvarchar(max)') as MalzemeAdi,
N.C.value('(ColumnData)[2]','float') as Miktar,
N.C.value('(ColumnData)[3]/@datatext','nvarchar(max)') as Birim,
N.C.value('(ColumnData)[3]','nvarchar(max)') as BirimKodu,
convert(float,replace(N.C.value('(ColumnData)[4]','nvarchar(max)'),',','.')) as onhand,
convert(float,replace(N.C.value('(ColumnData)[5]','nvarchar(max)'),',','.')) as minFiyat,
convert(float,replace(N.C.value('(ColumnData)[6]','nvarchar(max)'),',','.')) as ensonalfiyati,
convert(float,replace(N.C.value('(ColumnData)[7]','nvarchar(max)'),',','.')) as fiyat,
convert(float,replace(N.C.value('(ColumnData)[8]','nvarchar(max)'),',','.')) as Toplam,
N.C.value('(ColumnData)[9]/@datatext','nvarchar(max)') as ted,
N.C.value('@row','int') as d

FROM
(select convert(xml,VALUE) AS T22 FROM INST_DATA_MEMO WHERE CIID=57267  AND  DID=10021) T2
cross apply T2.T22.nodes('/LineItemTable/TableData/Data') N(C) )  t5
```

Comment: can't see any "?" in your code, where do you want to use it?

Comment: CIID=57267 
.
CIID=?